# jQuery next() selector when divs are not neighboring

Tags: jquery-selectors

Ive been using the following to change the width of the div.my-div that appears after the one you've clicked:

```
$(".my-div").click(function () {
    $(this).next().css({'width':'500px'});
});
```

As my divs were neighboring, this worked fine:

```
<div class="my-div">stuff</div>
<div class="my-div">stuff</div>
<div class="my-div">stuff</div>
```

However now the structure has changed so they are no longer neighboring:

```
<div>
  <div class="my-div">stuff</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="my-div">stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="my-div">stuff</div>
```

Whats the simplest way to select the next element of the same class? 
Thanks

Comment: FYI: Your markup is a little confusing. If your indentation is correct, then you just forgot to add the `/` to the closing `div` tags. I would have fixed it, but wasn't sure which you intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery will return elements in order of their appearance in the DOM.

As such, you could cache all the `.my-div` elements, use the [`index()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method to get the index of the one that received the event, increment it and use the [`eq()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get the next one.

```
var divs = $(".my-div");  // cache all of them

divs.click(function () {
    var idx = divs.index( this );  // get the index in the set of the current one
    divs.eq( idx + 1 ).css({'width':'500px'}); // get the one at the next index
});
```

This saves you from doing a bunch of unnecessary DOM selection and traversing.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/VrATm/1/

---

**EDIT:** *Posted wrong example link. Fixed.*

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the tree hierarchy. That is, you can first jump to parent, then to next, then to children, like this:

```
$(this).parent().next().find(' > div').css({'width':'500px'});
```